# Do I have to wait for startup to complete even when the database is in recovery mode if I specify -w on Windows?

Tags: postgresql

Normally, when the command to start server is given as `pg_ctl.exe -D ..\data -o"-p8028` -w start", the server waits until startup gets completed.

But my scenario is, I had forcefully shutdown the server using the `-m immediate` option. Then I tried to start the server with the command `pg_ctl.exe -D ..\data -o"-p8028" -w start`. While starting the server after immediate shutdown, it will move into the recovery mode.

So my question is, while starting the postgres server after immediate shutdown with the command `pg_ctl.exe -D ..\data -o"-p8028" -w start`, whether it will wait for the recovery mode to complete or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, even when we start the PostgreSQL server with the command

```
pg_ctl.exe -D ..\data -o"-p8028" -w start
```

it will not wait until the recovery mode is complete. It will wait for the time that we have specified during startup.